# which 3m filter for painting?

Tags: paint, safety

I am repainting a door using spray cans.  I am planing on giong through about 6 can... 1 primer, 2 paint, and 3 clear coat.

I have a 3m respirator that I plan on wearing but which filters should I use?

Is a particulate filter good enough?  Or do I need an "organic vapor" filter, etc?  I don't mind how much the filter cost but I want to make sure that I am filtering out all I can.

Comment: This question might have a better chance of answering at http://diy.stackexchange.com/ Give it a try!

Comment: @KromStern I thought about that.  But whenever I ask a question there they tell me its off topic :/ the people here are much more open to slightly off topic questions.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect DIY question to me. Either way I suggest removing door from frame and doing the paintjob on open air. Sorry I cant help ontopic better.

Comment: I would vote to close if it would be migrated to DIY, otherwise I leave it open as it is.

Answer (score 3):

The type of filter you need will depend on the type of paint you will be using. Consult the paint manufacturers web site. Look at the MSDS (material safety data sheet). A section of the form contains what is required for PPE (personal protective equipment). You then need to consult the 3M website to match a filter for the paint and the mask that you will be using.